# Akka-Quartz-Scheduler not triggered in Play for Scala

Tags: scala, akka, quartz-scheduler

I'm trying to implement [Akka-Quartz-Scheduler](https://github.com/enragedginger/akka-quartz-scheduler) in Play for Scala. Problem is that the scheduler is never triggered.

This is my quartz.conf, I'm trying to trigger an event every minute:

```
akka {
  quartz {
    defaultTimezone = "UTC"
    schedules {
      cronFirst {
        description = "job that fires off every minute"
        expression = "0 0/1 * * * ?"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I initiate the scheduler by invoking a page that calls the `test` method - this seems to work fine:

```
class Test @Inject() (system: ActorSystem) extends Controller {

    def test = Action { request =>

         val scheduler = QuartzSchedulerExtension(system)
         val receiver = system.actorOf(Props(new HelloActor))
         val d = scheduler.schedule("cronFirst", receiver, "Peter", None )

         Ok(d+"")
    }
}
```

And this is the actor that is never invoked (`println` is never executed):

```
object HelloActor {
  def props = Props[HelloActor]

  case class SayHello(name: String)
}

class HelloActor extends Actor {
  import HelloActor._

  def receive = {
    case SayHello(name: String) =>
      println( "Hello, " + name)
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Problem was that the message was incorrect. This fixed the problem:

```
val d = scheduler.schedule("cronFirst", receiver, HelloActor.SayHello("Peter"), None )
```